# Hypercorn - Can't find __main__ module in folder

Tags: python, pipenv, quart, asgi, hypercorn

I'm using Quart(Flask async) with debug=True and its builtin Hypercorn server, but everytime I save a file and the application tries to restart, I get :

> C:\Users\myusername.virtualenvs\App-GtW9WS3s\Scripts\python.exe:
>   can't find '__main__' module in 'C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive'

I think this is related to Hypercorn but it honestly could be anything and the questions about this error have a huge array of different solutions.

Worth nothing that I'm running Pipenv in Windows 10.

run.py :

```
from app import app as application

application.run(debug=True, host="gabriel.corp.carusojrea.com.br")
```

app/__init__.py :

```
from quart import Quart

app = Quart('__main__')

from app import views
```

Comment: Can you show the application python file, i.e app.py or whatever name it is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Quart [documentation](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/quart/quickstart.html), you'll have to use `__name__` instead of `__main__`.

```
from quart import Quart

app = Quart(__name__)
```

And according to the Class [documentation](https://github.com/pgjones/quart/blob/master/quart/app.py):

```
Arguments:
    import_name: The name at import of the application, use
    ``__name__`` unless there is a specific issue.
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Thank you! Totally missed that